# Convert Fahrenheit temperature value to Celsius with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, temperature

In my device_events table I have a sensor column which contains an array of sensor data. I have specifically pulled temperature from this array, however temperate is captured in our system as Fahrenheit. It is not defined anywhere to be Fahrenheit, but any device in our system reports Fahrenheit. I would like to query this data but return the Fahrenheit value as Celsius and so I'm wondering if there is any way to apply the calculation as part of the SQL query. Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT 
   de.device_created_at AS "Event Created",
   de.lat,
   de.lng,
   de.sensors->"temperature" AS "Temperature",
FROM device_events de
```

The calculation is (°F − 32) × 5/9 = °C, but I'm unsure how I can fit it in to the query to be applied to the value returned.

[image: device-events table]

Comment: Hint:  C = (F - 32) * 5/9; F = (C * 9 / 5) + 32.

Comment: I have included the calculation above, however I'm uncertain how to implement it as part of the query. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3):

SQL does arithmetic:

```
(de.sensors->"temperature" - 32) * 5.0 / 9 AS temperature_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table holds temperature in Fahrenheit, you can easily convert it in Celsius by applying the given mathematical formula.

Sample SQL -

```
SELECT 
   de.device_created_at AS "Event Created",
   de.lat,
   de.lng,
   de.sensors -> "temperature" AS "Temperature_in_Fahrenheit"
   ((de.sensors -> "temperature") - 32)*5/9 AS "Temperature_in_Celsius"
FROM device_events de
```

Alternate solution  -

```
SELECT t.*, (t.Temperature_in_Fahrenheit - 32)*5/9 AS "Temperature_in_Celsius" FROM (SELECT 
   de.device_created_at AS "Event Created",
   de.lat,
   de.lng,
   de.sensors -> "temperature" AS "Temperature_in_Fahrenheit"
FROM device_events de) t
```

Comment: Thank you. I use (de.sensors -> "temperature") because de.sensors has an array of sensor data. Example, {"light": "Dark", "humidity": 0.0, "temperature": 83.48}. So I am just looking to pull temperature and then convert it.

Comment: Okay got it.  Thank you for confirming.

Comment: But it seems the above doesn't work because I'm pulling from that array. My code when I try to apply the calculation is failing at the "->" piece

Comment: putting de.sensors -> "temperature" within open/close bracket works?

Comment: No :/ `ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb * integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 336
       de.sensors->'temperature' AS "Temperature",
       ((de.sensors->'temperature') - 32)*5/9 AS "Temperature_in_Celsius",
                                      ^
       de.sensors AS "Sensors",`

Comment: I have refactored the sql bit. Please try alternate solution. It should work.

Comment: `ERROR: column t.temperature_in_fahrenheit does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "t.Temperature_in_Fahrenheit".
  Position: 14
SELECT t.*, (t.Temperature_in_Fahrenheit - 32)*5/9 AS "Temperature_in_Celsius" FROM (SELECT 
             ^
   de.device_created_at AS "Event Created",`.         --Afraid not, thank you so much for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

It took some playing around with the format for the query to run successfully, but the key piece was converting the value type to float using `::float`. We don't always receive a value for temperature, so it helped in the case temperature was missing.

```js
SELECT de.device_created_at AS "Event Created",
de.lat,
de.lng,
de.sensors ->>'temperature' AS "Temperature F",
((de.sensors ->> 'temperature')::float - 32) * (5.0 / 9) AS "Temperature c" 
FROM public.device_events de
```